# WooCommerce unable to change content within template file

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

There is a line of code that I cannot change within the WooCommerce Template files. This line of code is displayed at the top of the view order page within my account / orders / view order

This is the code displayed in the inspector;

```
<p>Order #<mark class="order-number">58</mark> was placed on <mark class="order-date">3rd July 2018</mark> and is currently <mark class="order-status">Cancelled</mark>.</p>
```

And the only code I can find which is similar is in the tracking.php template file;

```
<p class="order-info"><?php
    /* translators: 1: order number 2: order date 3: order status */
    echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_tracking_status', sprintf(
        __( 'Order #%1$s was placed on %2$s and is currently %3$s.', 'woocommerce' ),
        '<mark class="order-number">' . $order->get_order_number() . '</mark>',
        '<mark class="order-date">' . wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) . '</mark>',
        '<mark class="order-status">' . wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) . '</mark>'
    ) ) );
?></p>
```

The problem is that this code has a class on the p tag the one in the inspector doesn't. And if I edit this code there are no changes on the front end. But the code looks the same so I'm not sure if this is the correct template file for this code?

Where can I find this code in the template files or is this the correct file and something is going wrong?

Comment: If you completely comment this section on the WooCommerce plugin file, does it still echos? if yes, it might coming from a template file override, or it's not that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another instance here: `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\myaccount\view-order.php` on line 30. Is that the what you are looking for?

Comment: Thats it thanks. I have no idea why this wasn't showing when I command F searched all the files.

Comment: I did the same. Just searched "order-number" in notepad++. You're sorted now anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If you completely comment this section on the WooCommerce plugin file, does it still echos? if yes, it might coming from a template file override, or it's not that file.

If this is the code, you should be able to add filter with the highest priority to change the content.